# Funky width percentage and mobile view in html email

Tags: css, html, image, html-email

I'm coding an email (no style sheet) and I can't get this section to do what I want it to. I want the links and the images side-by-side, but also when in the mobile view have the links go under the images. I have that fine (just mentioning for clarification).

I'm trying to get the two images to sit side-by-side even when the width is reduced to typical phone size, eg 400px. But when I enter **`width="50%"`** like so:

```
<img border="0" hspace="0"
     name="ACCOUNT.IMAGE.315"
     src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs127/1107749317607/img/315.jpg"
     style="display: block"
     vspace="0"
   / width="50%"
     >
     <figcaption align="center">Time to Shine
     </figcaption>
</a>
```

into the code below, it gets skewed.

**Before:** http://i60.tinypic.com/33lnvvo.png

[image: Before]

**After:** http://i62.tinypic.com/2uol6e0.jpg

[image: After]

My end goal is to have them side-by-side as in the first image, but in the smaller width. Currently it ends up looking like this even with the width% change: http://i58.tinypic.com/2qbyu7l.png

What is affecting the width?
Please help!
(Using MyEmma email service, supports HTML5)

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="textEdit" style="background-color: #FFF" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #555" styleclass=" style_MainText" valign="top">
<table align="right" class="imgCaptionTable" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<!-- INSERT LINK IN QUOTES, ex: <a href="LINK HERE"> --><a href="http://whartonmagazine.com">
<img border="0" hspace="0" name="ACCOUNT.IMAGE.315" src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs127/1107749317607/img/315.jpg" style="display: block" vspace="0"/><figcaption align="center">Time to Shine</figcaption></a></td>
<td>
<!--INSERT LINK IN QUOTES, ex: <a href="LINK HERE"> --><a href="http://whartonmagazine.com">
<img border="0" hspace="0" name="ACCOUNT.IMAGE.315" src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs127/1107749317607/img/315.jpg" style="display: block" vspace="0"/><figcaption align="center">Time to Shine</figcaption></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div style="font-size: 10pt; color: #981E32"><span style="font-family: Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif">Also in this issue: </span></div>
<div align="left" style="text-align: left; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #625467"><br/>
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #625467"><a href="http://whartonmagazine.com" shape="rect" style="font-family: Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #002C77"><span>Gracing the Class With TelePresence</span></a></p></div>
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #625467"><br/></p>
<div style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #625467">
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-family: Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt"><a href="http://whartonmagazine.com" shape="rect" style="color: #002C77"><span>Faculty Shine During Wharton MBA Reunion</span></a></p>
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-family: Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt"><br/></p>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #625467">
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-family: Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt"><a href="http://whartonmagazine.com" shape="rect" style="color: #002C77"><span>ReBlog: Save the Ultimate Asset for Yourself</span></a></p>
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-family: Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt"><br/></p>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #625467" styleclass=" style_SocialMediaText">
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-family: Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; color: #002C77; font-size: 10pt"><a href="http://whartonmagazine.com" shape="rect" style="color: #002C77"><span>Watch List: Top Wharton Social Entrepreneurs</span></a></p>
<br/>
</div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Appears fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/xeh1dbzn/

Comment: I believe the only email clients that reliably "supports HTML5" are the ones on Apple devices. Unless all your recipients are use them, I'd suggest reconsidering your approach. What you see rendered in your specific browser or device is not the same as what your recipients see in their inbox. Also, a ```figcaption``` is used to be used within the ```figure``` element, but shouldn't be used in email at all. Why not just a ```span``` for the text that's adjacent to the image?

Comment: I'll try doing that. Trying to get used to thinking differently for emails. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the same content in twice, once in a desktop version and again in a mobile version.

FWIW, as mentioned by @Narong, only a limited number of email clients support HTML5 - the big exceptions are Outlook and Gmail, which together usually account for around 30%. Add in older and more obscure clients, and that will typically go up to around half your recipients. Avoid `<div>`s, `<p>`s, `margin`, `padding` for anything structural, unless you're doing that inside a responsive stylesheet.